# How to fetch data using App Routes from NextJS and Prismic? I'm currently only being able to render uid fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, prismic.io

I'm using Prismic and NextJS. After reading their documentation on how to fetch data using the new App folder, I created this `src/[uid]/page.jsx` file

```
import { createClient } from "@/prismicio";

export default async function Page({ params }) {
  const client = createClient();

  const page = await client.getByUID("post", params.uid);

  return <main>{page.uid}</main>;
}
```

Which is returning the `uid` just fine.

The problem arises when I try to fetch whatever other data. In my schema (custom type) a few fields like `title` and `content`. But whenever I try to make `{page.title}` it doesn't work. I get no error from it, it simply doesn't render anything.

I tried a few things to fix this. First, I tried this snippet from the Prismic documentation itself

```
import { createClient } from "@/prismicio";

export default async function Page({ params }) {
  const client = createClient();

  const page = await client.getByUID("page", params.uid);

  return <main>{page.data.title}</main>;
}
```

But I get the following error. And by the way, `titulo1` is the value passed to the `uid` field in my documents within Prismic.

> Error: [function at(..)] unexpected field 'my.page.uid' on line:1
> col:6 in query '[[at(my.page.uid, "titulo1")]]' [[at(my.page.uid,
> "titulo1")]]

I also tried removing the `params.uid`. That gets me an error as well.

Then, I tried doing something like this: `const page = await client.getByUID("post", params.uid, params.title);`

But this simply have no effect and changes nothing.

Finally, tried to simply use `params` as some of their examples. In that case I'd get the following error

> Error: ']' expected but '[' found on line:1 col:2 in query
> '[[at(my.post.uid, [object Object])]]' [[at(my.post.uid, [object
> Object])]]

I don't know if this is relevant or not but my `prismicio.js` route configuration is this

```
const routes = [{
    type: "post",
    path: "/:uid",
  },
];
```

Also, as it could be related, when I try to query all documents of type `post` using the snippet they have in their documentation I get an error as well.

```
import { createClient } from "@/prismicio";

export default async function Page() {
  const client = createClient();

  const pages = await client.getAllByType("post");

  return (
    <ul>
      {pages.map((page) => (
        <li>{page.data.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

And the error is

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {type, text, spans}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
> use an array instead.

So, I'm confused on how to move forward as I tried to replicate what they have in their documentation but I'm failing to do so. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> But I get the following error. And by the way, titulo1 is the value passed to the uid field in my documents within Prismic.
>
> > Error: [function at(..)] unexpected field 'my.page.uid' on line:1 col:6 in query '[[at(my.page.uid, "titulo1")]]' [[at(my.page.uid, "titulo1")]]

This could happen if your custom type does not have a `uid` field. It does not, add a `uid` field and ensure the custom type is a "Repeatable" type.

> Then, I tried doing something like this: const page = `await client.getByUID("post", params.uid, params.title);`

The third argument, `params.title`, is not valid; the third parameter is an object of options. Passing `params.title` will not have any affect on `getByUID`.

> Finally, tried to simply use params as some of their examples. In that case I'd get the following error
>
> > Error: ']' expected but '[' found on line:1 col:2 in query '[[at(my.post.uid, [object Object])]]' [[at(my.post.uid, [object Object])]]

This happens because passing objects to the second argument of `getByUID()` is invalid; it must be a string UID value (e.g. `params.uid`).

> …And the error is

> > Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, text, spans}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

If your `page.data.title` property is a rich text field, you will need to use `@prismicio/react`'s `<PrismicRichText>` or `<PrismicText>` component to render the value.

You can learn more about the components and how to use them here: https://prismic.io/docs/technical-reference/prismicio-react#prismicrichtext